# Python Keep-Alive proxy connection with urrlib3

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, keep-alive, urllib3

I use the following method to maintain a Keep-Alive connection through a proxy to the target site.

```
import http.client

proxies = {"https": "https://user:pass@host:port"}
url = urlparse(proxies["https"])            
auth = '%s:%s' % (url.username, url.password)
headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic '+base64.b64encode(auth.encode('utf-8')).decode()

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(proxy.hostname, proxy.port)
conn.set_tunnel("target_site.com",headers=p_headers)
conn.request("POST", "/tapi/", payload, headers)
```

However,  HTTPSConnection is not thread safe. I am trying to do connection through urllib3 so that I will be able to use multiprocessing. My code doesn't work. What is the wright way to do it?

```
import urllib3
default_headers = urllib3.make_headers(proxy_basic_auth="user:pass")
conn=urllib3.HTTPSConnectionPool('https://target_site.com',maxsize=2,
         _proxy="https://host:port/", _proxy_headers=default_headers)
conn.request("POST", "/tapi/",fields=payload, headers=headers)
```